# title not being printed within html tag

Tags: loop

I am wrapping html tags around `the_title();` like

```
if(has_post_thumbnail()) { 
  the_post_thumbnail('home-thumbs');
   echo "<span class='home-title'>".the_title()."</span>"; 
}
```

But the `the_title` is printing above `<span>`, not like what i want. am i missing something? or doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

found the problem, the tags need to be inside the `()` like `the_title('<span>','</span>')`